# Figure refs stop working after I added a new counter

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, counters

I was using the `amspset` document class for generating exam practice problems. I had wanted to add some referencing to the problems so I started a new counter like this (adapted from some Tex Exchange post)

```
\newcounter{P}
\newcommand{\plb}[1]{\refstepcounter{P}\label{#1} \textbf{P-\ref{#1}.}}

\begin{problem}
\plb{p1}
A parallel-wire transmission line is constructed of \#6 AWG copper wire
(diameter $d=0.162$ in., conductivity $\sigma_c=5.8\times 10^7$ S/m) with a
12-inch separation in air. Assuming no leakage between the two wires, find
$R'$, $L'$, $G'$, and $C'$. Assume a working frequency of 1 MHz.
\end{problem}

\begin{solution}
Using Table.~\ref{tab:tlparam} and Fig.~\ref{fig:tlempl}, 
\[ Rs = \sqrt{\pi f \mu_c/\sigma_c} = 2.61\times10^{-4}~ \Omega\]
\[ R' = \frac{2R_s}{\pi d} = 4.04\times10^{-2} ~\Omega\text{/m} \]
\[ L' = \frac{\mu_0}{\pi} \ln{\frac{2D}{d}}=2.0~\mu \text{H/m} \]
\[ C' = \frac{\pi \epsilon}{\displaystyle\ln{\frac{2D}{d}}}=5.56 ~\text{pF/m}
\] $G'=0$ because the problem states that there is no leakage between the two
wires.
\end{solution}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{centering}
    \includegraphics{fig24}
    \caption{(Fig.2-4 from FAE) A few examples of transmission lines.}
\end{centering}
\label{fig:tlempl}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{(Table 2-1 from FAE)Transmission-line parameters $R'$, $L'$, $G'$,
and $C'$ for three types of lines.}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \hspace{3cm}\includegraphics{tb21}
    \end{tabular}
\label{tab:tlparam}
\end{table}
... and more
```

Now all the figure references stop working, I get "Fig. " instead of "Fig. 1". The table references are alright though. Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Could you turn your code snippet into a complete MWE? It will help folks who want to try and help.

Answer (score 2):

You are incorrectly using the `\centering` instruction:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{centering} % <- wrong!
    \includegraphics{fig24}
    \caption{(Fig.2-4 from FAE) A few examples of transmission lines.}
\end{centering}
\label{fig:tlempl}
\end{figure}
```

There is a `\centering` command, not a `centering` environment (even though LaTeX doesn't raise an error and works). Rather write

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
  \includegraphics{fig24}
  \caption{(Fig.2-4 from FAE) A few examples of transmission lines.}
  \label{fig:tlempl}
\end{figure}
```

The problem with your code is that the reference from `\caption` is formed inside a group, so the subsequent `\label` command cannot "see" it.